# Text Mining in R using Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a data frame. Lets say the data looks like this-

```
A <- c(1,2,3)

B <- c('a','b','c')

C <- c('d','e','f')

df <- cbind(A,B,C)
```

Now I would like to convert this data frame into a corpus where each column is treated as a document and each row as a term. When I use `Corpus(VectorSource(df$A)`, it convert the column in to as many document\topics as their are rows. Is it possible to achieve what I am aiming at.
The larger picture is that I want to use LDA(topic modeling) to identify column names in csvfiles that come without header by training the model on a large set of files that do have headers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response john. The below for loop solved my problem how ever--

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {                                                      
text_string <- as.character(df[,i])
text_string <- paste(text_string,collapse=' ')
x <- rbind(x,text_string)                                        
column_name <- rbind(column_name,colnames(df)[i])                                              

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `quanteda` package. It's mcuch faster and more intuitive than `tm`.

I'm a bit confused with your example however. What are your documents?

Generally:

```
dfm <- dfm(documents, tolower = TRUE, stem = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE,
          remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)
```

This is versatile enough to take most documents as an unedited character vector and return a document-term matrix. To reverse the rows and columns:

```
require("quanteda")
require("magrittr")

dfm <- dfm(documents, tolower = TRUE, stem = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE,
          remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  t()
```